# How can I fix the navigation bar to go to the top of the screen in a tabView?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I'm trying to create a TabView that contains a NavigationView. However, the navigation bar does not reach the top of the screen. How can I fix this?

[image]

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        TabView {
            NavigationView {
                TestView()
            }
                .tabItem {
                    Image(systemName: "star")
                    Text("Tab 1")
                }

            Text("Tab 2")
                .tabItem {
                    Image(systemName: "star")
                    Text("Tab 2")
                }
            Text("Tab 3")
                .tabItem {
                    Image(systemName: "star")
                    Text("Tab 3")
            }
        }
    }
}

struct TestView: View {
    var body: some View {
        List {
            Text("Hello")
        }
        .navigationBarTitle("Title")
    }
}
```

Comment: This seems to be fixed in Xcode 11.4 beta 2, so hopefully the workaround with `.edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.top)` will not be necessary anymore

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following view modifier will help you

```
.edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.top)
```